# Angular 4 removing duplicates from an Array Object

Tags: json, angular

I am having json array object in my Angular 4 application  and where i need to find out unique space type in my JSON array.

Json Array:

```
[{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Hospital_Lab"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_OpenOffice"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Hospital_Lab"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_OpenOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_OpenOffice"}},{}]
```

I want to remove all the duplicate space type .Can anyone tell me how i can get. 
I want the result :

```
[{Idx:0,Label:"Office_PrivateOffice"},{Idx:1,Label:"Office_OpenOffice"}]
```

Comment: this is pure javascript data manipulation. you can write a function to do that or you can use lodash or underscore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use lodash method **`_.uniqWith`**

```js
var jsonarray =  [{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Hospital_Lab"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_OpenOffice"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},
{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Hospital_Lab"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_OpenOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_PrivateOffice"}},{"label":{"Space_Type":"Office_OpenOffice"}},{}];


var filtered =  _.uniqWith(jsonarray, _.isEqual);

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The lodash method  `_.uniqBy(root, 'duplicateElement');` can also be used.  The advantage of using this method is that you can tell lodash which element you would like to remove duplicate of.

```
var newJsonFile = _.uniqBy(label, 'Space_Type'); 
console.log(newJsonFile);
```

In Angular, you would need to download package `lodash`

```
npm install lodash
```

Then import it

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```